# Deseleccionar celda en UitableView

Tags: swift2, swift, xcode

Quiero que se cancele que celda se selecciono.
Al darle clic a la celda seleccionada manda el idCategoria a la siguiente vista pero al darle regresar sigue seleccionada la celda y al querer dar clic en otra categoria muestra los de la categoria anterior

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        print(indexPath)

        vcName = values[indexPath.item]["idCategoria"] as! String

        //tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("show", sender: indexPath);
        //tableView.reloadData()


    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "show") {



            if let vc: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController {
                vc.idCategoria = vcName



            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que te pasa. que te queda la celda marcada? con el deselectRow que tienes comentado debería quitarse la seleccion

Answer (score 0):

En el método `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`, del `UITableViewDelegate` debes escribir la siguiente línea:

```
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

Finalmente quedaría así:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comprueba, también, que en la celda no hayas puesto nada haciendo referencia a la selección de esta. Para ello puedes sobreescribir el método **setSelected** del `UITableViewCell`.